# Unknown provider: tProvider <- t

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-formly

I get this error only on minified code (production).
bug was created when I add 'controller' function inside formly..
Please look up my code, maybe you will see some bug..
Any tips will be useful ;)

Dependencies:
"angular-formly": "~7.1.2",
"angular-formly-templates-bootstrap": "~6.1.0",

My code of controller:

```
.controller('NSearchBoxOnResultsController', ($rootScope) ->
    @formFields =
      [
        type: 'form_with_own_classes'
        key: 'q'
        defaultValue: @resultAsValue
        templateOptions:
          type: 'string'
          label: ''
          placeholder: I18n.t('homepage.placeholder')
          wrapper_class: 'row input--primary modal__center-items search search_query'
          input_container_class: 'col-xs-12'
          onKeypress: ($viewValue, $modelValue, scope, event) =>
            if event?.which == 13
              @submit()
        controller: ($scope, $rootScope) =>
          @scope = $scope
          @rootScope = $rootScope
          @rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', (newValue, oldValue) =>
            if @scope.options?.formControl
              @hash = window.location.hash.split('/')
              @queryFromHash = @hash.slice(2, @hash.length).join('/')
              @resultAsValue = decodeURIComponent(@queryFromHash)
              @scope.options.formControl.$setViewValue(@resultAsValue)
              @scope.options.formControl.$rollbackViewValue()
          )
      ]

    @submit = =>
      window.location = "/search/#all/#{@search.q}"

    @
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to explicitly inject $rootScope:

instead of `($rootScope) -> {code...}`

use

`['$rootScope', ($rootScope) -> {code...}]`

Otherwise, the '$rootScope' dependency is implied from the variable name. As $rootScope becomes $t during your minification angular implies you want to inject '$t' which doesnt exist.

google ng-annotate which automatically 'explicifies' your injections.

edit: I'm not familiar with coffeescript, so please bear with me :)

Comment: But when I don't inject $rootScope in main controller formly also working - but the same bug. I think injection in main controller no change anything..

Comment: `controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', ($scope, $rootScope) => {}]`. You should really look up ng-annotate. It's gonna handle all of this for you.

Comment: Here are all the good ways to do this, and the bad ones. I experienced this error when minifying angular-sanitize with Webpack. But using strictmode: `ngStrictDi` in the `ng-app`-element, fixed the error. I used the controller like this in JS:

`.controller('GoodController2', GoodController2);
function GoodController2($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}
GoodController2.$inject = ['$scope'];`

[unpr](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) & [ngApp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)